# Changing __init__.py not detected

Tags: python, python-2.7, rabbitvcs

I am trying to hack in a fix to [RabbitVCS](http://rabbitvcs.org/) by altering `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs/\__init__.py` but for some reason, any changes I make to this file are not detected. I deleted `__init__.pyc` and that also had no effect.

Can anybody shed some light on what I might be missing. I am still a bit green with larger python apps like RabbitVCS.

The reason for the hack is to work around RabbitVCS ([bug 139](https://github.com/rabbitvcs/rabbitvcs/issues/139)) which makes it unusable

Comment: Are you certain that that is the right location? What does `import rabbitvcs.vcs; print rabbitvcs.vcs.__file__` tell you the location is?

Comment: `import rabbitvcs.vcs; print rabbitvcs.vcs.__file__` returns `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rabbitvcs/vcs`

Comment: No `/__init__.py` at the end?

Comment: I double checked and no.

Comment: That's... intriguing. I don't see any weird import switcheroo going on in the module. I'm out of time for now to see what the module is doing, but I'd have expected that to result in a file reference (ending in `.pyc`).